# How do I hide the object the particles are on?

Tags: rendering, particles

I'm using a hair particle system to spread objects over another but I want the object to be transparent or gone in the final render.

Answer (score 5):

There is a checkbox for that in the Properties editor, Particle Properties tab, Render panel:

[image]

Comment: this didn't end up working in the final render and didn't find our till nearly an hour into the render

Comment: It definitely works. There is the same setting in Render and Viewport Display panels, maybe you set it only in Viewport Display panel.